# How to create a type alias for a queue.SimpleQueue?

Tags: python, queue, alias, typedef

I am just trying to create type alias to built-in `SimpleQueue` like:

```
import queue
import typing

my_queue_t = queue.SimpleQueue(maxsize=10)
```

However I get following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'queue' has no attribute 'SimpleQueue'
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `SimpleQueue` is new in Python 3.7 according to the docs.  What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also, note that what you're doing is not a type alias; you're simply trying to construct a single `SimpleQueue` object.

Comment: Version 3.6.8. How do I create a type alias say for a queue.Queue ?

Comment: `MyQueue = queue.Queue` should work fine.  You can assign any value to a variable, including a class/type.  No special syntax is needed.

Comment: What about type alias for a fixed size array: my_arr_t = array.array('B', [0,0,0]). Would this work ?

Comment: No, because `array('B', [0, 0, 0])` returns an instance, not a type.  I don't think you want a type alias, I think you want a function that constructs the thing you want and returns it.  It's hard to know for certain without seeing more context.  Type aliases and `TypeVar`s and `NewType`s have many uses but I don't think this is one of them.  :)

Comment: SimpleQueue is a type, but "SimpleQueue of maximum size 10" is not a type. Not all categories of Python objects are types.

Comment: @Samwise can I not create a type alias to array.array of a specific type here 'B' which is unsigned char and specific size say 3 ? Is type aliasing only applicable for built-in types ?

Comment: What you're describing is not a type alias; it'd be more like a subclass.  I'll submit an answer that illustrates that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing isn't really a type alias -- you're not simply creating a reference to `SimpleQueue`, you're defining a new class with different semantics (namely that `maxsize` is fixed at 10).  The typical way to accomplish that is via a subclass:

```
from queue import SimpleQueue

class MyQueue(SimpleQueue):
    def __init__(self):
        SimpleQueue.__init__(self, maxsize=10)
```

Another option would be to define a factory function that creates a `SimpleQueue` with your desired options:

```
def my_queue_t() -> SimpleQueue:
    return SimpleQueue(maxsize=10)
```